# Chrome Driver for chrome 57 does not accept enable-save-password-bubble=false

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have created a fb scrapping app using Python 3.x and Selenium package. 
Recently I updated to Chrome 57 browser and I get the latest chrome driver as well.
In this new version, the message to save passwords always popped after any successful login. I try to use the `--enable-save-password-bubble=false` parameter without success.
My code fragment is the following:

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-save-password-bubble=false")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
    browser.get("http://www.facebook.com")
```

Do i miss something obvious or something is changed in Chrome 57?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    'credentials_enable_service': False,
    'profile': {
        'password_manager_enabled': False
    }
})
```

This worked for me.
Refer to [the answer by Steve Saporta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42985071)